# File.Copy requires administration rights in ProgramData folder on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, file-copying, admin-rights

I am having some trouble making a simple file copy on Windows 8.1 from a folder in ProgramData to another folder within ProgramData. What i want to do is a backup of some application data.

When my code executes without administrator rights no file is copied. But when i run my application using administrator rights everything works fine and the filecopy is succesfully done.

My code is written in C# and is very simple and can be seen below:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);

File.Copy(sourceFile, Path.Combine(destination, backupFile), true);
```

I know this code works because as previously mentioned - the backup is done just only with admin rights. The user of my application does not necessarily have admin rights so it must work without this.

I have of course researched this but found no one in similar situation.

So Windows 8.1 must be different compared to previous Windows version regarding permissions in application data?

Is it possible to change permissions on destination and source file when doing a copy?

Comment: If it were possible to change the permissions when doing the copy, what would the point of the permissions system be? Within `ProgramData`, you should be working within a directory dedicated to your program, and the correct permissions on that directory should have been set up correctly once (e.g. by your installer program) so that, if all users need to be able to read and write within that directory, those permissions are assigned.

Comment: The user has the following permissions to the folder: Full Control, Modify, Read and execute, List folder Contents, Read and Write. So i guess the permissions are as they should be :)

Comment: After more research i have found out that the file copy was working! But instead of being copied to the applications data it was coped to a virtual store folder for the user. But why it was copied there i dont know.

Comment: Sounds like UAC Data Redirection is kicking in.